# Todas las rutas (route) de Laravel devuelven ERROR 404

Tags: php

Acabo de crear mi primer proyecto con Laravel, y estoy siguiendo todos los pasos poco a poco. Pero me encuentro estancado con un error que no consigo solucionar.

Al editar el fichero **web.php** en el directorio **routes**, ocurre que ninguna ruta que añada funciona. Sólo funciona la ruta principal a la raíz. Todas las demás devuelven **ERROR 404**.

Ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return  ('bienvenida');
});

Route::get('/hola', function()
{
    return ('hola mundo');
});
```

Al abrir **dominio.com/public/** obtengo el mensaje "**bienvenida**".

Al abrir **dominio.com/public/hola** obtengo un **error 404**.

Sin embargo, si voy a **dominio.com/public/index.php/hola** obtengo el "**hola mundo**".

Este no es el funcionamiento que deberían tener las rutas. Es decir, no debería tener que escribir "index.php" para continuar escribiendo la ruta. ¿Alguien conoce este problema y sabe solucionarlo?

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: PD: Uso Laravel 5.7.17 y mi versión de PHP es 7.2

Comment: como estas lanzando el servidor?

Comment: el servidor es un hosting contratado con php7.2

Comment: ahhhh ya me parecia! pense que estabas probando en local. Ahora me percado de "dominio.com" ja! Estas realizando mal el proceso de deploy me parece. Editaste el archivo index?

Comment: No he tocado el fichero index. ¿Qué debo modificar? Pensaba que el index del directorio /public no debía modificarlo.

Comment: [Mirá este tutorial](https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6) te explica como subir correctamente tu aplicación. Dependiendo del hosting puede que necesites crear un archivo .htaccess. Saludos!

Comment: Cual es el directorio público de tu servidor(no me refiero al de laravel)?

Comment: Te refieres a /homepages/6/duser/htdocs/ ?

PD: He seguido el tutorial y sigue igual.

Answer (score 1):

En linux ubuntu 20.04, con laravel 8 y php 8 lo solucioné de la siguiente forma en la terminal:

**Abrir el archivo de configuracion de apache2**

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**Dentro del archivo de configuración ir**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
</Directory>
```

**Cambiar el parametro de AllowOverride, de esta forma se activa mod _rewrite de Apache**

```
AllowOverride All
```

**Reiniciar apache2**

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución. Aunque no entiendo bien los detalles de por qué funciona así.

He entrado al panel de administración de mi "dominio.com", y he hecho que apunte directamente a /public. De esta forma, ya no es necesario poner dominio.com/public. Dominio.com lleva directamente a public.

Además, he editado el htaccess dentro de public y he añadido RewriteBase /

Queda de la siguiente forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Otro detalle que a lo mejor merece mencionar, es que esto me ocurre con un hosting contratado de 1and1 (ahora Ionos). Buscando soluciones para este problema, las personas que preguntaban tenían en común que todo esto les ocurre con este tipo de hosting.